# \openssl-1.1.1w\include\openssl/asn1_mac.h(10): fatal error C1189: #error: "This file is obsolete; please update your software

Tags: openssl

I am migrating old openssl version openssl-0.9.8i with VS-2012 to openssl-1.1.1w with VS-2017.

I am getting below error:
"..\openssl-1.1.1w\include\openssl/asn1_mac.h(10): fatal error C1189: #error:  "This file is obsolete; please update your software."

In older version "asn1_mac.h" has some different content and in newer version has only line saying "his file is obsolete; please update your software."

Could you please help me to understand which file i need to refer for newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this openssl-users thread](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2019-April/010239.html) and see if that may be of help. I remember there was some guide from the OpenSSL team to migrate past 1.0.0 but I can't find it now.